# Objective-C Substring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I'd like to know how to grab everything inbetween `http:// and /`

*NOTE: The IP address will change depending on environments and it may be a hostname instead of an IP address. I need to be able to handle both.*

e.g.,

```
http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/chocolate
```

Output:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Ehrm… use NSURL??! And an IP adress can also be a hostname, if it's not always one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a URL. Why not use something like

```
[[NSURL URLWithString:theString] host]
```

That will return the hostname part of the URL, which in your example is `127.0.0.1`. If you actually need a full URL that contains just the host, you could also try something like

```
[[NSURL URLWithString:"/" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theString]] absoluteURL]
```

Comment: The http part can be accessed using `scheme`, so once you build the url you can actually use `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [url scheme], [url host]]`.

Comment: That will produce "http/127.0.0.1". Not exactly what you want.